# Make two layers editable in leaflet draw

Tags: leaflet

I use Leaflet draw to draw markers and polygons on a map. The created features are saved to two separate feature groups. One feature group for the markers and one for the polygons. Now I want to edit the features. How can I add two feature groups as editable layers:

```
'edit': {
  'featureGroup': featureGroupMarker, featureGroupPolygon
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving it by adding twice the Leaflet drawControl to the map. One time for markers and one time for the polygons. This way I can specify which layer should be edited.

Comment: Can you please provide code on how you made this work? I am trying to do it for one layer (to be able to edit it after I load the layer through WFS) but I can not figure out how to do it. I have posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612818/how-to-edit-a-wfs-layer-with-leaflet-draw

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, but I assume I did it the following way: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#adding-the-edit-toolbar